# Input Validation not Occurring on Deployed SCA Version

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitecommerce

I have a really weird error where my registration form is not validating new input fields (gender, date of birth) when deployed. But that exact same code is validating on my local SCA Mont Blanc.

I have done a full deploy, ie, `gulp deploy`.

I have overridden the `Account` module. And my  `Account/Javascript/Account.Register.Model.js` file has the following validation added:

```
//@property {Object} validation. Backbone.Validation attribute used for validating the form before submit.
validation: {
    firstname: { required: true, msg: _('First Name is required').translate() }
,   lastname: { required: true, msg: _('Last Name is required').translate() }
,   email: { required: true, pattern: 'email', msg: _('Valid Email is required').translate() }
,   company:  { required: SC.ENVIRONMENT.siteSettings.registration.companyfieldmandatory === 'T', msg: _('Company Name is required').translate() }
,   password:  { required: true, msg: _('Please enter a valid password').translate() }
,   password2: [
        { required: true, msg: _('Confirm password is required').translate() }
    ,   { equalTo: 'password', msg: _('New Password and Confirm Password do not match').translate() }
    ]
,   gender: { required: true, msg: _('Gender is required').translate() }
,   dobday: { required: true, msg: _('Date of birth is required').translate() }
,   dobmonth: { required: true, msg: _('Date of birth is required').translate() }
,   dobyear: { required: true, msg: _('Date of birth is required').translate() }
,   phone: { required: false, pattern: 'digits', msg: _('Phone or Mobile number is required').translate() }
}
```

I have added the inputs to `LoginRegisterOverrides@1.0.0/Templates/login_register_register.tpl`. I wont show all of them but here is the gender input:

```
<div class="login-register-register-form-controls-group" data-validation="control-group">
    <label class="login-register-register-form-label" for="register-gender">
        {{translate 'Gender <small class="login-register-register-form-required">*</small>'}}
    </label>
    <div class="login-register-register-form-controls" data-validation="control">

        <select name="gender" id="register-gender" class="login-register-register-select" data-action="selectgender" data-toggle="select-gender">
            <option value="">
                {{translate '-- Select --'}}
            </option>
            <option value="1">
                Male
            </option>
            <option value="2">
                Female
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've confirmed that my module `ns.package.json` files are overriding the correct files. Plus it works locally (`gulp local`) so I know they are setup properly.

What could be the issue/problem why the inputs dont validate when deployed but they do locally?

Below is from my local SCA website (the Gender and DOB inputs validate correctly).
[image]

Below is from my deployed/online SCA website:
[image]

Comment: It seems like your new model is not added into the list of javascript dependencies of the Checkout. Have you checked your distro.json?

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Thanks for your comment. I haven't created any new models though. I have overridden the `Account.Register.Model`. But I wouldn't need to add/change that in distro.json would I?

Comment: If you are using the same name of the .js file in your custom model you shouldn't. Have you tried cleaning the distribution folders `gulp clean && gulp local` and browser cache? Also make sure that your override appears in the overrides summary when you run the local server.

Comment: @AndrésAndrade Thanks for your comment. `gulp clean && gulp local` didn't work unfortunately. *Do I need to add my module `LoginRegisterOverrides` to distro.json in `tasksConfig/javascript/dependencies` for the `MyAccount` application?* I've added that module to distro.json in the `modules` area.

Comment: If you are just overriding files in your module it doesn't need to be added into javascript dependencies since the original module is already there, but make sure that you are using the same name than in the original model `Account.Register.Model`. If you can upload a screenshot of you module, package.json and distro.json that would be helpful. Btw, for javascript files, it's a better practice to extend the original file instead of overriding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after dozens of hours trying to fix this, it turns out the error was down to the case of the 's' in my `JavaScript` module folder.

In `ns.package.json` I had:

```
{
    "gulp": {
        "javascript": [
            "JavaScript/*"
        ],
    },
    "overrides": {
        // Problem here Should be /JavaScript/ not /Javascript/
        "suitecommerce/LoginRegister@2.1.0/Javascript/LoginRegister.Register.View.js": "Javascript/LoginRegister.Register.View.js",
    }
}
```

Wow, I'm on Windows, so that file path was valid locally but the NS servers must be Linux. If it is, why wouldn't SCA devs just make all folders lowercase with underscores for christ sake!